# How to use Reactjs code to develop windows desktop application

Tags: javascript, windows, reactjs, cross-platform

Essentially we have been working on a product and we used Reactjs to develop web client but now there is a requirement for windows desktop application can we use Reactjs code to develop a windows desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Electron](https://electronjs.org/).

> If you can build a website, you can build a desktop app. Electron is a
>   framework for creating native applications with web technologies like
>   JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. It takes care of the hard parts so you can
>   focus on the core of your application.

The section 'Apps built on Electron' is a great start as you might recognise some applications that are built using Electron and you are using it already. Given the understanding of possibility, they have excellent documentation and a starting video, both linked on homepage.

Comment: @priyaranjhansingh thanks for your response but we want to use existing redux actions, reducers for some reasons.

Comment: encounter the conclusion after one week of research electron-react-boilerplate is a best option to opt.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are developing your desktop app. For example; if you are using ElectronJS to develop your app, you can use your react code for front-end purpose. Should work just fine.

Officially react doesn't support desktop yet. There are some libraries with several issues and long term support can't be guaranteed. Some libraries are -

https://reactdesktop.js.org/
https://proton-native.js.org/